# Which behavior have two sequential MutableLiveData.post() calls

Tags: android, concurrency, android-livedata

I am trying to learn more about Android `LiveData`. I am relatively new to Android Architecture Components so I am trying to figure out how the following call works "under the hood".

Having the following code:

```
 MutableLiveData<String> livedata1 = new MutableLiveData<>();
 MutableLiveData<String> livedata2 = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

**Calling the following code on a Worker Thread:**

```
livedata1.post("String");
livedata2.post("String");
```

Will the `livedata1` always be set on the main thread first then the `livedata2`?

From my understanding these calls will be dispatch to a queue to be run on the **main thread**. However does this queue run things in a sequential manner or the available CPU resources pick them up, making impossible to know which call will be set first?

Comment: By refering this link https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData.html#postValue(T) means that last value gets updated once main thread gets execution. so may be for your case, there're two different livedata can receive random execution on main thread because both instance are not same.

Comment: You should probably use something else. MutableLiveData is not designed as a tool to solve concurrency.